# POWER BI - KPI conditional formating text

Tags: text, powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting, kpi

I ve a table like the image below

[image]

I can have either Percentage or Integer, or Text data type (na, nav, available quarterly)

My Question is: Does exist a visualization that could display the Value, The Target and a Conditional Formatting (this could be an imagine, a colour, a symbol, an additional column, whatever) for every KPI even if I have Text data type?

Of course there is no need for the conditional formattig wherever we have: na, nav, ava quarte
However I would like to see in the Value and Target the na, nav etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would add steps to the query to force the data type for those columns to Decimal, then replace errors with **null**.  You could apply this to duplicated copies of each column if you need to preserve the original data.

Then you could use the conditional formatting in the Table visual, or try the Custom Visuals: Power KPI Matrix, Card with States.